# Get assets urls from assetic group in controller (not template) Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I wonder if how could I load an assetic group of assets from inside my controller.

my config.yml:

```
assetic:
  assets:
    systemassets:
      inputs:
        - 'bundles/belkapanel/js/*.js'
        - 'bundles/belkapanel/router.js'
```

Using twig, the solution is very simple:

```
{% javascripts '@systemassets'%}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

it will resolve the path wildcard and generate an single .js file with the content of all files found inside "systemassets".

However, I want to get the generated .js file inside an controller. I know it is possible, but reading the symfony's assetic-bundle I only found AsseticHelper with "javascripts" method, but I don't know how to use it, I think it is used after the packagename and wildcards are resolved.

```
/** @var DynamicAsseticHelper $asseticDynamic */
$asseticDynamic = $this->get('assetic.helper.dynamic');

$assets = $asseticDynamic->javascripts('systemassets'); // Doesn't work!
```

I'm looking at AsseticTokenParser, I think it is the solution, am I right? can someone help me find the solution?

Comment: @takeit Thank you for answering, but it doesn't work as well. I get the same error as using the example I provided.

    Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_5fdca40" as such route does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$assets = $asseticDynamic->javascripts(array('@systemassets'));
```

See this documentation [chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#using-named-assets) for more details (check PHP version).